# Excel VBA: Paste Contents From Other Workbook Into Active Workbook Sheet2

Tags: vba, excel

As the title says, the below is my attempt at (within my active workbook) opening another workbook, copying its contents, then pasting it within my current workbook's 2nd sheet. But I'm unable to pass the act of pasting. I've been unable to find relevant examples online to this particular case.

```
Sub SL()
Dim x As Workbook

Set x = Workbooks.Open("C:\Stuff.xlsx")

x.Sheets("SheetName").Cells.Copy

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Cells.PasteSpecial

End Sub
```

Can someone just explain what I should be putting in there, please?

Comment: Does the workbook "Stuff.xlsx" actually have a tab/sheet called "SheetName"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the following will give you a helping hand to achieve what you expect:

```
Sub SL()
Dim x As Workbook

Set x = Workbooks.Open("C:\Stuff.xlsx")

x.Sheets("SheetName").Cells.Copy
'does your workbook actually have a Sheet named "SheetName"?
'if not, you need to reference the sheet that you want to copy

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Cells.PasteSpecial

x.Close False
'close your "Stuff" workbook without saving
End Sub
```

Comment: "ThisWorkbook"! Perfect. Thanks @Xabier. And yes, I just renamed them to SheetName, Stuff, etc. for simplicity.